# AutoIT: Missing Wend for While

Tags: while-loop, autoit

All,

Below is the code that I have written in AutoIT.

```
    $fileToWrite = FileOpen("C:\output.txt", 1)

If FileExists("C:\test.csv") Then
    $fileHandle= FileOpen("test.csv", 0)
    If ($fileHandle = -1) Then
        MsgBox (0, "Error", "Error occured while reading the file")
        Exit
    Else
        While 1
            $currentLine = FileReadLine($fileHandle)
            If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop
            $days = StringSplit($currentLine, ",")
            FileWrite($fileToWrite,$days[2] & ", " & $days[9] & @CRLF)
            EndIf
        Wend
    EndIf
Else
    MsgBox (0, "Error", "Input file does not exist")
EndIf

FileClose($fileToWrite)
FileClose($fileHandle)
```

And the set of error:

```
C:\ReadCSV.au3(14,4) : ERROR: missing Wend.
            EndIf
            ^
C:\ReadCSV.au3(9,3) : REF: missing Wend.
        While
        ^
C:\ReadCSV.au3(15,3) : ERROR: missing EndIf.
        Wend
        ^
C:\ReadCSV.au3(3,34) : REF: missing EndIf.
If FileExists("C:\test.csv") Then
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
C:\ReadCSV.au3(15,3) : ERROR: syntax error
        Wend
        ^
C:\ReadCSV.au3 - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>Exit code: 0    Time: 3.601
```

I am not able to understand the issue here since I do have a Wend and EndIf for every While loop and an If condition. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the command `ExitLoop` after the `then`, there is no need for the `EndIf`.

(In this line: `If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop`)

You could either:

1. Remove the `EndIf`

   ```
   While 1
       $currentLine = FileReadLine($fileHandle)
       If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop
       $days = StringSplit($currentLine, ",")
       FileWrite($fileToWrite,$days[2] & ", " & $days[9] & @CRLF)
   Wend
   ```
2. Move the `ExitLoop` to the next line. (Which doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but the script will still run.)

   ```
   While 1
       $currentLine = FileReadLine($fileHandle)
       If @error = -1 Then
       ExitLoop
       $days = StringSplit($currentLine, ",")
       FileWrite($fileToWrite,$days[2] & ", " & $days[9] & @CRLF)
       EndIf
   Wend
   ```

I would go with #1.

Comment: If you were to use Option 2, you would have to move the EndIf to the line after ExitLoop.  Otherwise, the code after ExitLoop will never run.

Comment: @JohnForDummies : You're right. That's why I said that it didn't make much sense. You wouldn't want to execute that code anyway if the FileReadLine fails.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a `Endif` before the `Wend` and the `If` is already closed because you have `ExitLoop` over there.

So either remove the `Endif` or put the `ExitLoop` somewhere else.